# How to open a specific file, and write data in the next line over, and not delete previous data?

Tags: python, text-files, storage

I am fairly new to the world of programing. I am trying to write a program currently, that will ask for a username, password, and create an account. It will then save that account credentials in a text file. I am having trouble making it save in the same file, but one line down. It always deletes the previous data. Here is my code so far:

```
import linecache
username=input("Please Select a Username: ")
password=input("Please Select a Password: ")
password_again=input("Please re-type your password: ")
if password_again==password:
      print("Account Created Successfully")
      a = open('info.txt', 'w')
      with open('info.txt') as f:
          def file_len(fname):
              with open(fname) as f:
                  for i, l in enumerate(f):
                      pass
              return i + 1
      a.write("Username: " + username + "; Password: " + password + "; ")
      a.close()
      usernamenter = input("Please enter username: ")
      passwordenter = input("Please enter password: ")
      a.open('info.txt', 'r')
      a.readlines(linecache+1)
      if usernamenter == linecache:
       if passwordenter == linecache:
        print("Access Granted. Have a nice day")
      else:print("Username/Password is incorrect. Please try again :(")
else: print("Password does not match. Please try again")
```

I also have a problem with the program going in, reading, and ignoring the words, User, and Password. Including all colons. Can someone help? thank you.

Comment: thats what append mode is for. `open('info.txt', 'a')`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I hope you know that what you are showing us isn't at all right.  You are opening the same file over and over again, and defining functions where you shouldn't be.  Start with something very simple.  To add to a file, you open it in append mode, like `with open('info.txt', 'a') as f:`.  Write a few lines of code that just plays with that idea.  You should be able to do what you're trying to do in 6-12 lines of code.

Comment: `a = open('info.txt', 'w')` should be `a = open('info.txt', 'a')`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and welcome to the programming community! There are a few things to point out with your code. I believe you are overthinking this challenge. The reason you have been overriding the existing file text, is because you were opening your file with this: `a = open('info.txt', 'w')` instead of this: `a = open('info.txt', 'a')`. The 'w' stands for **write** and the 'a' stands for **append**. This was pointed out in the comments. In addition, as pointed out by CryptoFool, there are some random uses of `def`, which is used for defining functions, which is not necessary for this.

When saving data like this, it is usually good to use a data type. In this case, I decided to use dictionaries. Dictionaries are just a nice way of grouping data. You can learn more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). To convert the string in your file to a dictionary, you can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which is what I used below. Then finding the value of a dictionary word is as simple as `dictionary["term"]`.

```
import json

username = input("Please Select a Username: ")
password = input("Please Select a Password: ")

if password == input("Please re-type your password: "):

    print("Account Created Successfully")

    # Opening with "a" allows you to easily add/append to end of file.
    a = open("info.txt", "a") 

    # Creating a dictionary to hold our username and password.
    # This will make it easier to read our file data.
    # Dictionaries look like this: {"u" : "1", "p" : "2"}
    # "\n" is a new line.
    a.write('{"Username" : "' + username + '", "Password" : "' + password + '"}'+"\n")
    a.close()

    u_enter = input("Please enter username: ")
    p_enter = input("Please enter password: ")

    # This is just my way of getting the last line of a file
    with open('info.txt', 'r') as a:
        last_line = a.readlines()[-1]

    # We have to use json to convert string to dictionary
    savedlogin = json.loads(last_line)

    # Instead of having multiple if statements, we can use "and"
    if u_enter == savedlogin["Username"] and p_enter == savedlogin["Password"]:
        print("Access Granted. Have a nice day")
    else: print("Username/Password is incorrect. Please try again :(")

else: print("Password does not match. Please try again")
```

I wish you luck and I hope you learned a lot.